# Login form redirect_to doesn't seem to work

Tags: bigcommerce

[According to the docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/developing-further/modifying-forms#login-form-redirect) using the following code should redirect a user upon login to `/shop-all`

```
<input type="hidden" id="redirect_to" name="redirect_to" value="/shop-all">
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. A user is redirected to account or cart (if they have items in their cart)

Has anybody got a work around for this?

#### Steps to reproduce behavior

- Enter the line  `<input type="hidden" id="redirect_to" name="redirect_to" value="/shop-all">` into the form.html login form.
- Run stencil
- Log in to your BC Store

Comment: It works on my sandbox store, can you post the template perhaps? I edited the file templates/pages/auth/login.html and added the hidden element to the form, then after log in it redirected to shop-all as expected

Comment: Hi Andrew, to update this post as well as the post in our developer community; I filed a bug report for this, you can reference by STRF-8994, as I was testing quite a bit with my team yesterday and we received the same behavior as you. It is apparent that versioning may be a factor in this as it works per docs on some stores but not all. I included this information in the report so I can contribute an answer here once it's resolved. Thank you!